# Program to redirect all local traffic to port 80?

Tags: windows, port-forwarding

I recall using a program a long time ago, it was on Windows and would allow me to funnel all traffic generated on the machine to port 80.

I used it because I was on a proxy server, and some programs couldn't work right due to ports and such.

I'm looking for this or a similar program. Does anyone know of something?

Summary: I want to redirect all traffic on my machine through port 80.

Comment: I don't think you are not describing it adequately. What are you actually trying to do? Please be specific with the goals, and try not to offer a solution. Are you trying to proxy just HTTP traffic? As described, you can't run a computer. They need to use other ports.

Comment: For example: I used to be behind a proxy server. Some programs, such as PunkBuster, refused to work correctly.

I found a program that allowed me to "funnel" that traffic, from everything on my machine, to a different port. I am trying to find a similar solution now.

Comment: I understand now, but unfortunately, I really can't answer the question. At least what you are trying to do is now clear to anyone else, who may be able to.